# Event handler not working perfectly with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I am dynamically creating buttons which each selection of a dropdownlist.

With the following code I am adding an event handler to each button.

```
 button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);

 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);

 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //Do something...
     Response.Write("hello");
 }
```

But unfortunately it does not fire that event and gives me an error as following

> button_Click 'Index.button_Click(object, System.EventArgs)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

How do I handle this?

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Close", "javascript:OpenPopUp1();", true);

    if (Session["filter"] == DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        if (Session["filter"] == "")
        {
            Session["filter"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ":";
        }
        else
        {
            Session["filter"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ":" + Session["filter"];
        }
    }

    string asd = Session["filter"].ToString();

    string[] split = asd.Split(':');

    DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
    for (int i = 0; i < split.Count(); i++)
    {
        string filter = split[i].ToString();

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = split[i].ToString();
        button.ID = split[i].ToString();
        button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "remove(" + split[i].ToString() + ")");
        button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

The above shows the whole code of dropdownselected index.

Comment: *Where* are you putting that code? In a method? If so, which method?

Comment: button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);

 PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);                                        is being put under selection index change method

Comment: Please show the complete method.

Comment: I think you are explicitly invoking the method somewhere else with syntax `.button_Click` and you are not supplying the parameters to that method which needs to be supplied.. call the method with bracket and parameters supplied to it like:- `<objectName>.button_Click(<senderParam>, <eventArgsParam>);`

Comment: Move the *button_Click* method to beginning of class and compile again. I guess then the next function gets an error or?

Comment: i have mentioned the total code of the particular event

Comment: Are you still looking for more answers to this question? Or have you solved it in another way you can share with the community?

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click); 
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button); 

 } // <-- end your current method with a curly brace


 // Now start a new method
  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        //do something... 
        Response.Write("hello"); 
    }
```

Comment: i still think you've got a syntax error - if you are using Visual studio look for the red wiggly lines under something...

Comment: ok, i'm out of ideas but when i've seen that particular error, it's always been related to a typo I made somewhere... that's just my experience

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you're going after, as there are a number of issues going on here.  Since your dynamically generated buttons are being created in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler of your dropdown, they are not going to exist, nor are their event bindings, on the next postback.  This means they can show up on the page, but clicking them won't do anything.

Secondly, since you are storing the SelectedValue to Session, and then using that value to set the Button IDs, you are going to be creating buttons with duplicate IDs if the user ever comes back to the page.  (I noticed you are removing the list item once selected, but it would come back if the user refreshed the page, while the session object would remain populated.)

Last oddity, I wasn't able to find where your particular exception is handling, nor able to reproduce it.  Which version of .NET are you programming against?  Are you invoking the button click event anywhere from code-behind?

Now, that all said, I'm providing the following fix (or at least improvement):

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButtons();
    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Close", "javascript:OpenPopUp1();", true);

        if (Session["filter"] == DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (Session["filter"] == "")
            {
                Session["filter"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ":";
            }
            else
            {

                Session["filter"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue + ":" + Session["filter"];
            }
        }
        DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(DropDownList1.SelectedIndex);
        CreateButtons();
    }
    private void CreateButtons()
    {
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();

        if (Session["filter"] != null)
        {
            string asd = Session["filter"].ToString();

            string[] split = asd.Split(':');

            for (int i = 0; i < split.Count(); i++)
            {
                string filter = split[i].ToString();

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = split[i].ToString();
                button.ID = split[i].ToString();
                button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "remove(" + split[i].ToString() + ")");
                button.Click += new System.EventHandler(button_Click);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
            }
        }
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something...
        Response.Write("hello");
    }
```